# Performance en AJAX del lado del cliente

Tags: ajax, aplicación-web, rendimiento

Me gustaría saber cual de los dos métodos que voy a exponer a continuación son mas óptimos para el `Client Side` para implementar la paginación de resultados de una búsqueda:

1- Traer `todos los elementos` que arroja la búsqueda en un JSON, presentar solo una parte y a medida que cambia de página voy mostrando diferentes elementos a partir del JSON que ya tengo.

ó

2- Traer solo `los primeros N elementos` en un JSON y a medida que cambia de página pedir al servidor vía AJAX los elementos correspondientes.

Comment: No entiendo por qué la ponen en espera por basarse en opiniones. Yo creo que todo lo contrario, se basa en tecnicismos, no quiero saber que opinan, sino que me digan cual de las opciones son mas óptimas teniendo en cuenta la memoria, los diferentes dispositivos, la carga del servidor, etc. Además de la experiencia que hayan tenido frente a diferentes problemas para ahorrarmelos en un futuro

Comment: Si te fijas en las dos respuestas, se basan en opiniones y en experiencias que pueden variar de un ambiente a otro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada opción tiene sus `pros` y sus `contras`.

**OPCIÓN 1: Devolver todos los registros**

*PROS:*

- **Carga del servidor**: No es necesario volver a abrir una conexión al servidor cada vez que se aplique un filtro.
- **Rendimiento en el cliente**: Al aplicar un filtro/búsqueda, el tiempo de espera seguramente será menor.

*CONTRAS:*

- **Tráfico**: El volumen de datos (`bytes`) transferidos al cliente es significativamente mayor. Esto puede generar costos extras si se tiene una `quota` baja en el límite de salida de datos, así como también en móviles con paquetes de datos limitados.
- **Carga en memoria del cliente**: Almacenar mucha información en el cliente significa que este requiera mas `RAM`.

**OPCIÓN 2: Devolver `N` registros** (`paginar`)

Básicamente lo opuesto.

*PROS:*

- **Tráfico**: El volumen de datos (`bytes`) transferidos al cliente es significativamente menor.
- **Carga en memoria del cliente**: Almacenar poca información en el cliente significa que éste requiera menos `RAM`.

*CONTRAS:*

- **Carga del servidor**: Es necesario volver a abrir una conexión al servidor cada vez que se aplique un filtro.
- **Rendimiento en el cliente**: Al aplicar un filtro/búsqueda, el tiempo de espera seguramente será mayor.

Creo que la mejor opción depende del escenario que se presente.
Yo siempre me inclino por `paginar`, ya que por lo general, inicialmente uno siempre devuelve lo que el usuario quiere ver y lo demás es "`histórico`"

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer un benchmark al respecto pero siempre va a depender de la cantidad de registros que tengas. Si no sabes que tanto pueda crecer esa base de datos lo mas eficiente tanto en terminos de servidor como de cliente seria solo recuperar N resultados por request.

Comment: Podria indicarme a que se debe la calificacion negativa?

Comment: Siempre hay gente que no genera ningun tipo de aporte mas que votaciones negativas. No les des bola